# Saving project with layers as one compiled file?

Tags: qgis, geopackage

Is there a way to save a QGIS project as one large file that includes the layers it points to?

I am working with Tecplot quite a bit, which has the option of referencing individual data files or saving all the data as one compiled file. I was wondering if QGIS has a similar capability.

As long as layer locations don't change, I can simply point to the absolute layer location. However, if I want to create a backup disk or hand over the project to a third party, the folder structure may not be preserved.

I found some discussions about QCompile and GeoPackage, which should do what I want, but from what I understand they are still in development stage.

Answer (score 2):

I can only provide an alternative method which I use for colleagues and that is to create a single folder containing the Project file (.prj) and all the designated folders with each containing their relevant shapefiles. This provides a form of structure that my colleagues can recognise and easily follow.

The top-level folder (containing everything) is then compressed into a smaller, single file which can easily be sent to others via email, USB etc and all they have to do is decompress the file and load the project file. They can then make changes to the shapefiles or add/remove any, save those changes in the project file and send it all back to me without having to worry about preserving the file/folder structure.

I am not aware of QGIS having that facility of compiling all files into one but perhaps can shed some light into this matter.